# recursive mustache partial in ruby

Tags: ruby, recursion, mustache

I was trying to render a mustache template which is referencing itself in it. But it gives a 'Stack level too deep' error.

Here is my code in ruby.

## The following snippet of code is in person.rb file

```
require 'mustache'
require 'active_support'

str = File.read("person.json")
j = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(str)
Mustache.template_file = "person.mustache"
puts Mustache.render(j)
```

## The following json content is in person.json

```
{
    "name":"Jason",
    "rels":[
        {"type":"friend",
        "ref":{
            "name":"John",
            "rels":[
                {"type":"friend",
                "ref":{"name":"Chrissy"}}
            ]
        }},
        {"type":"family",
        "ref":{"name":"Owen"}}
    ]
}
```

## The following content is in the file person.mustache file

```
{{#rels}}
<ul>
  <li>Type: {{type}}</li>
  {{#ref}} {{> person}} {{/ref}}
</ul>
{{/rels}}
```

can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: modified my json file to have `{ "name":"Chris", "rels":[ {"type":"friend", "ref":{ "name":"Chessy", "rels":[ ] }}, {"type":"family", "ref":{"name":"Niels"}} ] }` But still had the same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html):

> **Partials**
>   [...]
>   They also inherit the calling context. Whereas in ERB you may have this:
>
> ```
> <%= partial :next_more, :start => start, :size => size %>
> ```
>
> Mustache requires only this:
>
> ```
> {{> next_more}}
> ```
>
> Why? Because the **next_more.mustache** file will inherit the **size** and **start** methods from the calling context.

So, if there is no `rels` in the current context:

```
    "ref": { "name": "Chrissy" }
```

then you'll inherit the `rels` from the parent. That gives you a partial referencing `rels` from the parent which activates the partial again which references `rels` from the parent which keeps going until you run out of stack.

If you're going to build a recursive template like this:

```
{{#rels}}
<ul>
  <li>Type: {{type}}</li>
  {{#ref}} {{> person}} {{/ref}}
</ul>
{{/rels}}
```

then you need to have complete objects at each level:

```
{
    "name":"Jason",
    "rels":[
        {"type":"friend",
        "ref":{
            "name":"John",
            "rels":[
                {"type":"friend",
                "ref":{"name":"Chrissy","rels":[]}} // <--- rels here
            ]
        }},
        {"type":"family",
        "ref":{"name":"Owen","rels":[]}} // <-------------- and here
    ]
}
```

You can flesh out your data in the JSON or after you parse it, I'd recommend that you flesh it out after parsing it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Now I could see how mustache figures out the end of the loop  during recursion.